# AJAX success for $.each array value NOT equal to value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a continuous AJAX call returning an array of IDs like (1, 17, 20) every few seconds which I am using to change classes of table rows with data-id equal to those values, which is working fine.

But I need to also impact those rows whose data-id is NOT equal to one of those values.

This is the part that works.

```
        success: function(data){ 
        $.each((data), function(index, value){
           var row = $("tr[data-id="+value+"]");
           $(row).addClass("ready");
           });
          }
```

However, when I replace var row with `$("tr[data-id!="+value+"]")` it is applying class change to all table rows. Obviously there is a conflict or improper process I am applying but have no clue where! Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to remove the class from all `tr` elements before adding it to those required. Also note that you can use `map()` to build a single selector string with all target `tr` elements, like this:

```js
success: function(data) {
  let filterSelector = data.map(v => `tr[data-id="${v}"]`).join(',');
  $('tr').removeClass('ready').filter(filterSelector).addClass('ready');
}
```

Working example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  // mock AJAX response
  let data = [
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  ];

  let filterSelector = data.map(v => `tr[data-id="${v}"]`).join(',');
  $('tr').removeClass('ready').filter(filterSelector).addClass('ready');
}, 1000);
```

```css
tr.ready {
  background-color: #0C0;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="0"><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="1"><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="2"><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="3"><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="5"><td>E</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="6"><td>F</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="7"><td>G</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="8"><td>H</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="9"><td>I</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="10"><td>J</td></tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much for such a quick and awesome reply! Both suggestions were great but I went with your map() code.

Comment: No problem, glad to help